# How to get Ubuntu Netbook Edition Unity layout layout in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, unity, customization

I saw [this article](http://digitalunion.osu.edu/2011/04/04/ubuntu-10-10-netbook-edition/) and liked the layout of Unity. I would like to have it on my Precise 64bit.

Also I want to keep my current settings, switching back to them whenever I want to.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before Unity introduced in Ubuntu 11.04 , Gnome was present in later versions as a default desktop. The article you read was written at April 2011. Ubuntu 11.04 was launched in April 2011 with Unity desktop. Unity is derived from that Netbook desktop and improved a lot after that in Ubuntu 12.04 within a year. The net book desktop was designed earlier than Unity.

Comment: So how to swap the layout? Or is it not possible?

Comment: You have already the best and stable Unity , rather than notebook addition, You can customize Unity with my unity and Ubuntu tweak tool.

Comment: @VedVals You *can't*  have that layout anymore unless of course you install 10.10 and install Unity (I believe it wasn't called that way back then)  or get the Netbook version of Ubuntu 10.10. And no it wasn't a beta version it was the Netbook Version desktop, but it got redesigned to what you see now.

Comment: K. Got it. Though it looked nice.